# Relevance score boost VS sort in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch, and got confused that should i use sorting or boost relevance score in my query.
If instead of sorting, i boost score on the same field used for sorting, , I’ll get the same result . So what exactly is the the recommended approach in to take ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boosting is for increasing/reducing importance of a field and it happens during the search process... Sorting is performed on the output of the search:

Let's say you have the following fields for `Student`:

- Name
- Surname
- Age

Now let's say you have the following records in your search engine:

```
{John, Smith, 12}
{Jane, Winston, 13}
{Winston, Peters, 11}
```

If you search the term: 'Winston' you get the following result:

```
Search Term: 'Winston'
SortBy: Default
Result: both results have the same score and either one may appear on the top
{Jane, Winston, 13}
{Winston, Peters, 11}
```

Now let's assume `Surname` is more important for you, then you will boost the field `Surname`:

```
Search Term: 'Winston' (Surname boosted)
SortBy: Default
Result: Jane Winston would have higher score because Surname is boosted
{Jane, Winston, 13}
{Winston, Peters, 11}
```

By default the result are sorted by relevance (i.e. score) but you can change the sort order... let's say you want to sort the same result by `Age`:

```
Search Term: 'Winston' (Surname boosted)
SortBy: Age
Result: Winston Peters appears first even though it has lower score
{Winston, Peters, 11}
{Jane, Winston, 13}
```